# Amazon Order API or Report API to get SKU number and total quantity sold?

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I want a list of all SKU for which there were any sales between the From Date and To Date with the quantity sold. I am all confused what to do - should I use Amazon MWS Order API for this or Report API for this? Does anyone have a c# code which shows how a report is requested and downloaded at my end for further processing i.e. saving the data in databases.
Any help would be much appreciated.

p.s. I have a large volume of data

UPDATE: Meanwhile I have written this code to get the report type and save the data. Now the error is "Access to path denied"

```
private const string targetRptType = "_GET_CONVERGED_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_";

try
{
    RequestReportRequest reportRequestRequest = new RequestReportRequest();
    reportRequestRequest.Merchant = merchantId;
    reportRequestRequest.ReportType = targetRptType;
    reportRequestRequest.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
    reportRequestRequest.EndDate = DateTime.Now;

    MarketplaceWebServiceConfig config = new MarketplaceWebServiceConfig();
    config.ServiceURL = "https://mws.amazonservices.com";

    MarketplaceWebService.MarketplaceWebService service = new MarketplaceWebServiceClient(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, applicationName, applicationVersion, config);

    RequestReportResponse requestResponse = service.RequestReport(reportRequestRequest);
    Thread.Sleep(15000);
    Response.Write(requestResponse.RequestReportResult.ReportRequestInfo.ReportProcessingStatus);
    GetReportRequestListRequest reportRequestListRequest = new GetReportRequestListRequest();
    reportRequestListRequest.Merchant = merchantId;
    List<ReportRequestInfo> myListzz = new List<ReportRequestInfo>();

    GetReportRequestListResponse reportRequestListResponse = new GetReportRequestListResponse();
    reportRequestListResponse = service.GetReportRequestList(reportRequestListRequest);
    GetReportRequestListResult reportRequestListResult = new GetReportRequestListResult();
    reportRequestListResult = reportRequestListResponse.GetReportRequestListResult;
    myListzz = reportRequestListResult.ReportRequestInfo;
    while (myListzz[0].ReportProcessingStatus.ToString() != "_DONE_")
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20000);
        reportRequestListResponse = service.GetReportRequestList(reportRequestListRequest);
        reportRequestListResult = reportRequestListResponse.GetReportRequestListResult;
        myListzz = reportRequestListResult.ReportRequestInfo;
    }

    GetReportListRequest listRequest = new GetReportListRequest();
    listRequest.Merchant = merchantId;
    listRequest.ReportRequestIdList = new IdList();
    listRequest.ReportRequestIdList.Id.Add(requestResponse.RequestReportResult.ReportRequestInfo.ReportRequestId);

    GetReportListResponse listResponse = service.GetReportList(listRequest);


    //MessageBox.Show(listResponse.GetReportListResult.ReportInfo.ToString());
    GetReportListResult getReportListResult = listResponse.GetReportListResult;

    GetReportRequest reportRequest = new GetReportRequest();
    reportRequest.Merchant = merchantId;
    reportRequest.WithReportId(getReportListResult.ReportInfo[0].ReportId);

    GetReportResponse reportResponse = new GetReportResponse();
    try
    {
        reportRequest.Report = File.Open("C:\\AmazonReport.csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);  // Getting error access to path denied
        reportResponse = service.GetReport(reportRequest);
    }
    catch (MarketplaceWebServiceException exe)
    {
        Response.Write(exe);
    }
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(reportRequest.Report);
    Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
    sr.Close();

}
catch (MarketplaceWebServiceException ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Can anyone please check my code and suggest if this is the correct way to get data from a report? I am still not able to save the report.

**UPDATE 2**
I have changed the path and now the error is gone and the file is created but it is just a 1 kb file with 2 records.. looks like it is not fetching full data. Not sure if the code is correct or not. Checking this on scratchpad https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: yes document is there, I agree. Initially I was using Orders API but that always took lot of time and gave throttling error and did not fetched data many times. Someone suggested to use the Report API to avaoid all the hassles. I am working on that - they do have a material but I was looking for the code examples as how to write things in C#. I did not find something easy to understand and follow, so just wondering if someone have already worked and have some inputs/suggestions. Anyhow thanks for the link.

Comment: I am stuck at getting the sales data from a Report API.. I want to get data from  _GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_ and looking for a simple c# code samples which explains how to get data.

Comment: Also the question says "Does anyone have a c# code which shows how a report is requested and downloaded"

Comment: And i Think the question explains what is neeed - "I want a list of all SKU for which there were any sales between the From Date and To Date with the quantity sold."

Comment: Ok, this is better - I've voted to reopen this question!  Which line gives you the "Access to path denied" error?

Comment: :), thanks.. I hope someone can suggest if this is how it should be coded.

Comment: On this line - reportRequest.Report = File.Open("C:\\AmazonReport.csv", ...) I am debugging it again with different path to check if it works.. otherwise have to find another way to save data in database

Comment: Well, with UAC turned on in WinVista+ (7,8,10...) you're not allowed to create files in the root of the `C:` drive.  Put it somewhere else.

Comment: @J...yes I changed the path and it is working now but the file seems to be incomplete :(

Comment: Probably worth asking a new question at this point.  You will always get a better response like this when you focus on the most immediate issue in a single question.  If you solve that issue and run into another problem then it's time to ask a new question.  This way the solution is broken down into smaller pieces that are more likely to have lasting utility for other people facing one of those specific issues (which is what Stack Overflow is all about).

Comment: @J...thanks for all the inputs, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I would save the report in your current working directory.  Access to C:\ is usually locked down unless you are running as an admin.  Use the following if you want to be explicit (if you provide just a file name and not a fully justified path, it will also save in your current working directory)

```
reportRequest.Report = File.Open(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "AmazonReport.csv"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Answer (score -1):

The Orders API would make this much easier in my opinion. You can request Orders using a Date range and get everything you need.

Comment: _p.s. I have a large volume of data_  Large volumes of data eliminates the Orders API.  If you look into the documentation on the Reports API, there is a reference that states something along the lines of anything greater than 200 orders should be pulled using Reports API.